# Adding and retrieving from a KeyedCollection

Tags: c#, collections, keyedcollection

I want to use a KeyedCollection to store a class against a string key value.  I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Key;
    public string Test;
}

public class MyCollection : KeyedCollection<string, MyClass>
{
    public MyCollection() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override String GetKeyForItem(MyClass cls)
    {
        return cls.Key;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyCollection col = new MyCollection();
        col.Add(new MyClass()); // Here is want to specify the string Key Value
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong here?  Where do I specify the key value so that I can retrieve by it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `GetKeyForItem` override is what specifies the key for an item. From the docs:

> Unlike dictionaries, an element of `KeyedCollection` is not a key/value pair; instead, the entire element is the value and the key is embedded within the value. For example, an element of a collection derived from `KeyedCollection<String,String>` might be "John Doe Jr." where the value is "John Doe Jr." and the key is "Doe"; or a collection of employee records containing integer keys could be derived from `KeyedCollection<int,Employee>. The abstract`GetKeyForItem` method extracts the key from the element.

So in order for the item to be keyed correctly, you should set its `Key` property *before* adding it to the collection:

```
MyCollection col = new MyCollection();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.Key = "This is the key for this object";
col.Add(myClass);
```

Comment: +1 - for researching and answering the question rather than simply saying 'use a Dictionary' - which is probably what I would've said.

Answer (score 1):

The `KeyedCollection` is a base class for creating keyed collections, so there is quite a lot that you need to implement yourself.

Perhaps using a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) would be easier and faster to work with.

Comment: Although Dictionary for general purposes is the preferred approach; KeyedCollections allow you to load an object into a collection where a member in the object is the key to the value of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's slightly different, but have you considered implementing an [indexer](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/1547581/Using-Indexers-in-C.htm).

```
public string this[string index]
{
    get { 
      // put get code here
    }
    set {
      // put set code here.
    }
}
```